# SQL Server 2008 R2 remote connection

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having problems making my ms sql server 2008 take remote connections, local workes fine.

- I have enabled the TCP/IP and the server browser server in the sql
  server config
- I have opened the ports in the firewall, have also
  tried shutting it down completly.
- I have made it so the server allow
  username/password logins.

What am i missing for remote connections to be allowed? The Sql Server 2008 R2 is running on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

I'd probably try disabling the Named Pipes protocol first to see if that makes a difference, since it always seems to cause me problems, check the SQL server and instance aliases to make sure they're correct, verify that your SQL server is listening on the default port (1433), and after that, consult a [SQL connectivity troubleshooting guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx) and/or my logs.  This is where error information would come in handy, because for all we know from what you've given us, the problem is that someone took a hammer to the NIC in your SQL box.

By the way, did someone take a hammer to the NIC in your SQL box?

(And, incidentally, why are you running SQL on Windows 7?  Icky.)